# Install Windows HDD into MacBook Pro and boot Windows 10 TP

Tags: hard-drive, macbook, windows-10-preview

I have two laptops. One is running Windows 10 Tech Preview and the other is a MacBook Pro.

My question is if I were to remove the internal Hard-drives from both computers and install the Windows HDD into my MacBook Pro and boot it up, will it run the Windows 10 TP on my Mac or will it return an error.

I can easily take both hard-drives out and physically replace the internal HDD of the Mac, I was simply wondering if it would work and if it would cause and disk corruption or data loss.

Comment: The drivers won't match. You'd be safer to do a clone with universal restore using something like Acronis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return an error. Mainly because Mac runs a custom "BIOS". But secondly because the hardware doesn't match, so most likely half of OSX will be broken or refuse to boot and the Windows 10 will refuse to boot.

To actually run windows on your Macbook, you have to use [bootcamp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468).

Comment: Is there anything I can do outside of bootcamp or using an external drive to make it boot the OS on my windows HDD?

Comment: No there is not, Apple uses a highly proprietary, self made BIOS, that can't interoperate with other systems, as it is a part of OSX. So if you remove the drive without doing a OSX copy or reinstall, you will have a 1000$ paperweight.

Comment: @Kris - Its not that proprietary honestly.  It uses a security module but it still follows the UEFI standard.  Of course most BIOS(s) are proprietary

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but it still has a very different setup to "normal" BIOS systems. In which that most of it is software controlled as part of OSX, which can on some machines render it useless or render you without possibility of updating the BIOS should the need arise, without OSX.